# Adding background image to div using CSS

Tags: css, html, background-image

I have been trying to add background image to a div class using CSS, but I didn't have any success.

HTML code:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-shadow"></div>
        <hgroup></hgroup>
        <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">

        </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
```

CSS:

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
}
```

Additional information:

This is an image with a shadow and I am using it at the top of the website, so it mustn't have a particular width.

Comment: There's no content in the `<div>`, so may have a height of 0, meaning you can't see it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to add a `width` and a `height` of the background image for it to display properly.

**For instance,**

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
    width: XXpx;
    height: XXpx;
}
```

As you mentioned that you are using it as a shadow, you can remove the `width` and add a `background-repeat` (either vertically or horizontally if required).

**For instance,**

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y; /* for vertical repeat */
    background-repeat: repeat-x; /* for horizontal repeat */
    height: XXpx;
}
```

*PS: XX is a dummy value. You need to replace it with your actual values of your image.*

Comment: How to manage the aspect ratio of the image as it's resized? It seems image is not shown but only th div when it's resized.

Comment: Use `background-size` property to achieve the same. You can read more about the same as below http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size - @aspiring

Comment: there can't be whitespace between 'url' and '('

Comment: @andrej - It doesn't matter.

Comment: Is there any solution to use it without a particular height ? To be 100% and accommodate to the place the image have ?

Answer (score 14):

Specify a height and a width:

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because `.header-shadow` is empty.

Add `height` to it:

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aUx7U/)

Comment: [Agreed - @Hiral](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064596/adding-background-image-to-div-using-css/20064619#20064619)

Comment: There is no image, color is fine, but when you remove color, there is no image, :(

Answer (score 1):

Add height & width properties to your .css file.

Answer (score 1):

**To use an image for body background in CSS**

```
body {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also for setting the class in a div section:

```css
/** CSS **/
.content {
    background: url('http://www.gransebryan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bryan-ganzon-granse-who.png') center no-repeat;
}

.displaybg {
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <p class="displaybg">This is just a test</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.content {
    background: url('http://www.gransebryan.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/bryan-ganzon-granse-who.png') center no-repeat;
 }

.displaybg {
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score -3):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"><!--
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .wrapper {
                margin: 0px auto;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 940px;
                background-color: #EEE;
                background-image: url("images/bg.png");
                background-repeat: repeat-y;
                padding: 0px 25px 4px 25px;
            }

            .header {

            }

            .headerIn {
                width: 940px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            .headerP1 {
                width: 940px;
                background: url("images/lines_tech.png") repeat;
                margin: 0px auto;
                height: 140px;
            }

            .container {
                width: 940px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-size: 14px;
                height: auto;
            }

            .footer {
                width: 100%;
                background: #EEE;
            }

            .footer {
                width: 940px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                /* background: url("images/footer_bg.png") center bottom no-repeat; */
            }

            .mainfooter {
                width: 990px;
                background: url("images/footer_bg.png") no-repeat;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .footer .footerContainer {
                width: 940px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

            #tblbdr table, #tblbdr table td {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
                padding: 5px 5px;
            }

            #tblbdr table, #tblbdr table td {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
                padding: 5px 5px;
            }

            .input {
                padding: 5px 5px;
                margin: 0px 0px;
                border: solid 1px #DEDEDE;
                background-color: #F9F9F9;
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            .tbl {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                background: url("images/tblbtm.png") repeat-x bottom;
            }

            .tbl1 {
                background: url("images/tblright.png") repeat-y right;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }

            .button {
                background: royalblue;
                color: #FFF;
                border: none;
                padding: 5px 7px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: square outside none;
            }

            ul li {
                display: block;
                height: auto;
                line-height: 29px;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: #F6F6F6;
                padding-left: 30px;
                font-family: Verdana;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
                background-image: url('images/arrowC.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: left -30px;
            }

            .DivTab1 {
                width: 270px;
                height: 199px;
            }

            .DivTab1 a {
                background-image: url('images/nav_bg.jpg');
                background-position: 0 0;
                float: left;
                display: block;
                width: 85%;
                height: 33px;
                line-height: 40px;
                padding-left: 40px;
                color: #000;
            }

            .DivTab1 a:hover {
                background-image: url('images/nav_bg.jpg');
                background-position: left 33px;
                float: left;
                display: block;
                width: 85%;
                height: 33px;
                line-height: 40px;
                padding-left: 40px;
            }
        --></style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="headerIn">
                    <div class="headerP1">Header</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container" id="tblbdr">
                <div class="tblt" style="padding:10px;background:#fff; width:500px;margin:0px auto;">
                    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500px">
                        <tr><td>Login</td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="text" class="input"  /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="text" class="input"  /></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <br /><br />

                <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl1">
                <table border="0" style="background:#fff;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="width: 79px">
                            State<span style="color: #ff0000">*</span></td>
                        <td style="width: 183px">
                            <select name="drpOwnerState" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'drpOwnerState\',\'\')', 0)" id="drpOwnerState" class="input" style="width:173px;">
                                <option value="NA">Select</option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="AN">ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS</option>
                                <option value="AP">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
                                <option value="AL">ARUNACHAL PRADESH</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 65px">
                            Division<span style="color: #ff0000"></span></td>
                        <td style="width: 187px">
                            <select name="drpOwnerDivision" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'drpOwnerDivision\',\'\')', 0)" id="drpOwnerDivision" disabled="disabled" class="input" style="width:173px;">
                                <option selected="selected" value="NA">Select</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 56px">
                            District<span style="color: #ff0000"></span></td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <select name="drpOwnerDistrict" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'drpOwnerDistrict\',\'\')', 0)" id="drpOwnerDistrict" disabled="disabled" class="input" style="width:173px;">
                                <option selected="selected" value="NA">Select</option>
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            Type any detail about your nearest KIOSK:</td>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <input name="txtSearch" type="text" maxlength="100" id="txtSearch" class="input" style="width:182px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="8" style="height: 23px">
                            <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" value="Search" onclick="return ListValidation();" id="btnsearch">

                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="lblExport" value="Export To Excel" id="lblExport"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br /><br />
        <div class="DivTab1" style="z-index: 750;">
            <a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=1">Applications</a><a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=2">
                Bill Payments</a> <a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=3">Counseling</a>
            <a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=4">Assessment</a> <a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=5">
                Religious</a> <a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=6">Reservation</a>
            <a href="/Portal/CitizenHome.aspx?servtypeid=7">Universities</a>
        </div>

        <br /><br />

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><spn>This is testing code which may be more or less.</span></li>
                <li>This is testing code which may be more or less. This is testing code which may be more or less.This is testing code which may be more or less. This is testing code which may be more or less.</li>
                <li>This is testing code which may be more or less.</li>
                <li>This is testing code which may be more or less.</li>
                <li>This is testing code which may be more or less.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        </div>


        <div class="footer">

            <div class="footerContainer">Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mainfooter">&nbsp;</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: ... And it looks like overkill for a simple question