# HTML div background image not working

Tags: html, css

The HTML `div` for the navigation bar design in CSS will not work.

CSS

```
/* CSS Document */

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:0px; 
}

body {  
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat scroll center top #13120d;   

    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;     
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px; 
}   

#header_menu_bg {
    background: url('../images/navigation.png') no-repeat center top;
    height: 198px;  
    width: 737px; 
}
```

This is just a short example.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="bla"/>
        <meta name="description" content="bla"/>
        <title>WEBSITE</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header_menu_bg">
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Where did your write the CSS? In the header or a seperate file? Don't forget to add a link to the css file <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

Comment: A Fiddle will help understanding your problem

Comment: Ya of course I have the CSS included @Johannes

Comment: the navigation.png just doesn't show up in the HTML document when the css and div are all good..

Comment: why haven't you width in css?

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't work'? Please clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064596/adding-background-image-to-div-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the URL to your image is correct.
2. Place the URL in between `'` or `"` tags (`url("../images/navigation.png")`)
3. Add a width to your div, f.e. `width: 200px;`

**EDIT:** When looking at your full HTML, you also need to close your `<body>` and `<html>` tags.

Your full code will look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="bla"/>
    <meta name="description" content="bla"/>
    <title>WEBSITE</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header_menu_bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:0px; 
}

body {  
    background-color: #13120d;  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;     
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px; 
}   

#header_menu_bg {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/737x198') no-repeat center top;
    height: 198px;  
    width: 737px; 
}
```

**DEMO: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ximagilo/1/) (JSFiddle doesn't seem to work at the moment)**

Comment: Unfortunately not. Try and explain the problem a bit more, add some code, anything that would help us help you.

Comment: Are the links to the images correct? Are the image files not corrupt/damaged? Is the path to your CSS correct? ...

Comment: hell ya they are correct, not damaged, ive just exported them from photoshop

Comment: Does it work if you use the images on the URL's I provided? Are you using the right file extension(s)?

Comment: But does it work when **replacing your paths with the ones I provided**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it a `width` attribute.

```
#header_menu_bg {
background: url(../images/navigation.png) no-repeat center top;
height: 280px;
width: 200px; }
```

EDIT

Check in the console log, to see if there are issues with the browser finding your image. Perhaps you have the wrong path.

EDIT 2

Close your `<body>` and `<div>` tags.

Comment: the div won't show up in the HTML, it doesn't display the navigation as intended

Comment: Is it perhaps somehow under another <div> in the document?

Comment: as said in other answers, you need quotes around the url for your image in the css.

Comment: ive added quotes with no luck

Comment: apparently there are no issues in the log, css linked to the right path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have referenced the css file correctly and no error in your html coding structure I suggest clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(../images/navigation.png) no-repeat center top;
```

you need "" or '' like this:

```
background: url('../images/navigation.png') no-repeat center top;
```

probably this helps you

Answer (score 0):

The following css works and puts an image in the DIV. Fiddle is not working at the moment and I can't put a link for it now.

```
#header_menu_bg 
{
    background-image: url('fnordware.com/superpng/pngtest16rgba.png'); 
    height: 32px; 
    width: 32px; 
}
```

You either have a wrong url or something else is wrong if this css doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Download the sample image from [Here](http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/2090/images/hero_small/Sumatran-Tiger-Hero.jpg) and save it as **bg.jpg**.

Create a new folder and put the 2 below files & a image in same folder.

**HTML** (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<head>
   <title>WEBSITE</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>        
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header_menu_bg">
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** (main.css)

```
body 
{     
background-color: #13120d;  
margin: 0;  
padding: 0;     
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 13px; 
}

#header_menu_bg
{
background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat center top;
width: 280px;  
height: 500px; 
}
```

**RESULT**:

[image]