# How do i insert a background image into a div using Css from desktop?

Tags: css

HTML Code:

```
<div class="circleBase type1">
```

CSS Code:

```
.type1 {
    background-image: url("/img/me.jpg");`
     width: 120px;
    height: 120px;  
    border: 1px solid black;
};
```

Comment: probably duplicate of: [adding-background-image-to-div-using-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064596/adding-background-image-to-div-using-css)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.type1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png");`
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="circleBase type1"></div>
```

Refer to this.

Comment: Hey Young. I did not downvote. I have actually liked your answer.